# Sequencia de fração com fibonacci e primos

Tags: c, fibonnaci

h. Solicite ao usuário a quantidade de termos que ele deseja e imprima a sequencia abaixo e a
   soma dos termos.
    1      +      1       +      2      +        3     +        5    +       8     +…
    2             3              5               7             11           13
   * em cima sequencia de Fibonacci e embaixo sequencia de Primos.

Tenho esse exercício pra fazer, mas não estou conseguindo. Quando jogo os dois juntos, altera tudo. Mas se fizer separado, consigo fazer a sequencia perfeitamente.

Como resolver?

Meu código até agora: http://pastebin.com/ChG2VDTv

```
#include "stdio.h"

main(){
    int qtd, n1=0, n2=1, f=0, p=2, cont=0, j;
    int a = 0;

    printf("Entre com a quantidade de termos: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtd);

    for(int i=0; i<=qtd; i++){
        cont=0;

        for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
            if (i%j==0){
                cont++;
            }
        }

        if(i!=0){
            if(cont==2){
                //printf("%d ", i);
                printf("%d/%d + ", f, i);
            }
        }

        /*if(i!=0){
            printf("%d + ", f);
        }*/

            n1 = n2;
            n2 = f;
            f = n1+n2;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seria interessante mostrar funcionando separado. Em tese não tem segredo nenhum juntar. A não ser que eu não tenha entendido alguma coisa, você faz uma lista e depois faz a outra, portanto não deveria ser difícil fazer junto.

Comment: @Michael, reverti a edição. Aqui não é um fórum, e não se muda a pergunta pra [resolvido]. Você pode postar sua solução como resposta e marcar como aceita, ou se alguma das respostas atendeu, basta marcar a respectiva resposta como aceita (é o V verdinho logo embaixo da pontuação da resposta): Aqui tem umas coisas legais pra entender o funcionamento do site: [help] e [FAQ da comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699).

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de calcular e imprimir; calcula e mete em arrays. Depois imprime os arrays.

```
int arrf[10]; // array para fibonacci
int arrp[10]; // array para primos

// calcula e guarda numeros
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    arrf[k] = calculaf(k); // falta a definicao
    arrp[k] = calculap(k); // das funcoes calcula*
}

// imprime linha com numeros fibanacci
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) printf("%4d ", arrf[k]);
puts(""); // fim de linha

// imprime linha com numeros primos
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) printf("%4d ", arrp[k]);
puts(""); // fim de linha
```